# How to create token in antlr4 lexer g4 file for IF () THEN abc ELSEIF () THEN xyz ElSE yzx ENDIF

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

Issue is i have written the lexer file and created the token like

```
IF_EXPR : 'IF';
ELSEIF_EXPR : 'ELSEIF';
THEN_EXPR : 'THEN';
ELSE_EXPR : 'ELSE'
```

But there are some cases where i can have  some string that contains 'IF' in the condition block or in side the THEN block. and it is considering the 'IF' in the string as as token.

Example:

```
IF abc=1 
THEN 
   xyzIF=3
ELSE 
   abc=2
ENDIF
```

In the above example my lexer is treating the 'IF' in xyzIF as a IF_EXPR token but it should consider xyzIF as one different token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `IDENTIFIER` rule define that would match `xyzIF`:

```
// Keywords first!
IF : 'IF';

// After keywords, define something that matches an identifier:
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
```

Comment: would ITENTIFIER : [.]* work? because the string can have anything (special char as well) ?

Comment: No, that is too greedy.